A question about smooth and effective finite group action
I encounter this question when trying to prove that if $f:O_{1}\to O_{2}$ is a diffeomorphism between two orbifolds $O_{1}$ and $O_{2}$, then the local group $G_{p}$ is isomorphic to the local group $G_{f(p)}$. The definition of orbifolds and local groups can see this paper. Kleiner, Bruce; Lott, John Geometrization of three-dimensional orbifolds via Ricci flow. Astérisque No. 365 (2014), 101–177.
Suppose $U$ is an open and connected subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. A finite group $G$ acts smoothly ($\forall g\in G, x\mapsto gx$ is smooth) and effectively (if $g_{1}, g_{2}\in G, g_{1}\neq g_{2}$, then as maps $g_{i}:x\mapsto g_{i}x, i = 1, 2$, we have $g_{1}\neq g_{2}$) on $U$. $p\in U, G_{p} := \{g\in G\mid gp = p\} = G$. For $g\in G$, suppose $g = (g^{1}, \dots, g^{n})$ as a map from $U$ to $U$, $Dg = (\frac{\partial g^{i}}{\partial x^{j}})$ is the matrix consists of the first order derivatives of $g^{1}, \dots, g^{n}$.
Can we prove that $\forall g\in G, g\neq e$, where $e$ is the identity element of $G$, we have $Dg(p)\neq I_{n}$? Here $I_{n}$ is the n-th order identity matrix.
M.H.A Newman has a theorem saying that if a finite group $G$ act continuously and effectively on a connected topological manifold $M$, then the points in $M$ which has trivial isotropy group form an open and dense subset of $M$. See A. Dress. Newman’s Theorems on Transformation Groups, Topology 8(1969), 203–207.
Here is my efforts to solve problem using the above theorem. Assume to the contrary that there exists $g\in G, g\neq e$ such that $Dg(p) = I_{n}$.
We claim that for any neighborhood V of $p$ there exists $q\in V$ such that $Dg(q)\neq I_{n}$. If not, then there exists a neighborhood $V$ of $p$ such that $Dg(q) = I_{n}$ for all $q\in V$. Since $g\in G_{p}$, we have $gp = p$, this means that $g = id$ in V. By the theorem of Newman, we can choose a point $r\in V$ such that $G_{r} = {e}$, it follows that $gr\neq r$, a contradiction. So the claim holds.
I got stuck at this position and do not know what to do next.

Yes, this is a standard fact. More generally:
Theorem. Suppose that $M$ is a (smooth) connected manifold, $G$ is a compact group of diffeomorphisms of $M$ fixing a point $x\in M$. Then $g\in G$ is the identity element if and only if $Dg_x=Id: T_xM\to T_xM$.
Proof. First of all, there exists a $G$-invariant Riemannian metric on $M$. In the case when $G$ is finite, this is particularly easy, take any Riemannian metric $h_0$ on $M$ and define
$$
h=\sum_{g\in G} g^*h_0.
$$
For general compact groups one uses a similar averaging argument, see
Koszul, J. L., Lectures on groups of transformations. Notes by R. R. Simha and R. Sridharan, Tata Institute of Fundamental Research Lectures on Mathematics and Physics. Mathematics. 32. Bombay: Tata Institute of Fundamental Research. 97 p. (1965). ZBL0195.04605.
I will now fix a $G$-invariant Riemannian metric $h$ on $M$ and take $g\in G$ such that $Dg_x=Id$. Next, let $U$ be a normal ball neighborhood of $x$ with respect to the metric $h$ (the exponential map $\exp_x$ is a diffeomorphism from a ball in the tangent space to $U$). Take a point $y\in U$ and the unique unit speed geodesic $c$ in $U$ such that $c(0)=x, c(T)=y$ for a suitable $T\ge 0$. Since $Dg_x=Id$, $Dg_x$ sends the tangent vector $c'(0)$  to itself. Hence, it sends the entire geodesic $c$ to itself and, hence, $c(y)=y$. Thus, $g$ restricts to the identity map on $U$. Lastly, take an arbitrary $y\in M$. There exists a piecewise-geodesic path $c$ connecting $x$ to $y$ (since $M$ is connected). Subdivide $c$ as a concatenation $c_1\star ... \star c_k$ of geodesic segments each of which is contained in a totally normal neighborhood. Now, using the argument as above for normal balls prove inductively that $g$ fixes each $c_i$ pointwise. Hence, $g=Id$. qed
A similar proof shows that the $G$-action is linearizable in a normal neighborhood of $x$, see Kuszul's paper.

I completely understand the process of proof, thank you so much!
